# when item is selected from list , that item is not displayed in textview(EditorFragment)

Tags: java, android

EditorFragment , textview : onclick, dialogfragment will open,
dialogfragment, two parts : a) searchfield b) recyclerview.
adapter , it handles, item selection from list.

EditorFragment code : in editorfragment, after slection of item, that item will display in textview;

```
    public class EditorFragment extends Fragment {

    public static TextView tv_custom_spinner;
    private Context context;
    SearchAdapter searchAdapter = null;
    List<SearchModel> searchModelList ;


    public EditorFragment(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
        searchModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        searchModelList.add(new SearchModel("First Name"));
        searchModelList.add(new SearchModel("Second Name"));
        searchModelList.add(new SearchModel("Third Name"));
        searchModelList.add(new SearchModel("Fourth Name"));
        searchModelList.add(new SearchModel("Fifth Name"));
        searchModelList.add(new SearchModel("Sixth Name"));

        searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(context,searchModelList);

        setResources(view);
        clickSpinner();
        return view;
    }

    private void setResources(View view){
        tv_custom_spinner = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_custom_spinner);
    }

    private void clickSpinner(){
        tv_custom_spinner.setOnClickListener(v->{
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            SpinnerDialogfragment spinnerDialogFragment= new  SpinnerDialogfragment(context, searchModelList);

            spinnerDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, "SPINNER");
        });

        searchAdapter.setUpdateDataListener(value -> tv_custom_spinner.setText(value));
    }
}
```

Adapter code :

```
public class SearchAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchAdapter.SearchHolder>{

    private Context context;
    private List<SearchModel> searchModelsList;
    private String title;


    public interface UpdateDataListener{
        void onItemSelected(String value);
    }

    public UpdateDataListener listener;

    public SearchAdapter(Context context, List<SearchModel> searchModelsList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.searchModelsList = searchModelsList;

        this.listener = null;
    }

    public  void setUpdateDataListener(UpdateDataListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SearchAdapter.SearchHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.search_item_list, null);
        return new SearchHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SearchHolder searchHolder, int position) {

        searchHolder.tv_searched_item.setText(searchModelsList.get(position).getItemTitle());

        searchHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            title = searchModelsList.get(position).getItemTitle();
            listener.onItemSelected(title);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return searchModelsList.size();
    }

    class SearchHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView tv_searched_item;

        public SearchHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tv_searched_item = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_searched_item);
        }
    }
}
```

error :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.coco.myapplication, PID: 25724
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.coco.myapplication.SearchAdapter$UpdateDataListner.onItemSelected(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.coco.myapplication.SearchAdapter.lambda$onBindViewHolder$0$SearchAdapter(SearchAdapter.java:53)
        at com.coco.myapplication.-$$Lambda$SearchAdapter$fc2DFbNCnzN7ljubXWaQ4mEoai8.onClick(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:782)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25945)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:874)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6729)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Process 25724 terminated.

Comment: your listener is null, try to set/update  in activity/fragment

Answer (score 0):

Initialise this `DataListener` in the `onViewCreated` method.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    searchModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    searchModelList.add(new SearchModel("First Name"));
    searchModelList.add(new SearchModel("Second Name"));
    searchModelList.add(new SearchModel("Third Name"));
    searchModelList.add(new SearchModel("Fourth Name"));
    searchModelList.add(new SearchModel("Fifth Name"));
    searchModelList.add(new SearchModel("Sixth Name"));

    searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(context,searchModelList);

    //Initialise  DataListener here
    searchAdapter.setUpdateDataListener(new UpdateDataListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(String value) {
            tv_custom_spinner.setText(value);
        }
    });

    setResources(view);
    clickSpinner();
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Updated, you never create the UpdateDataListener

Comment: searchAdapter.setUpdateDataListener(new SearchAdapter.UpdateDataListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(String value) {
                tv_custom_spinner.setText(value);
            }
        });

when lambda is used, that time, no need to create updateDataListener()

Comment: may i need to push the code of "SpinnerDialogfragment.java" ??

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment onviewcreated() call

```
setUpdateDataListener("pass your listner")
```

then try again. NUll expection should go away and it should work